# Parsing a comma separated file in a bash script with a while loop

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, scripting, command

I'm trying to parse a comma separated file similar to the following, and extract each field into a variable:

```
bob,mechanic,single,swimming,/bob/tmp,batman,
joe,architect,married,tennis,/joe/tmp,superman,34
```

With this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#|| [[ -n "$input" ]]

while IFS=, read -r a b c d e f g; do
    echo "$a"

done < "commafile.txt"
```

But when I run the script (called parsecommas) with ./parsecommas from the command line, the script terminates immediately without any output.

What am I doing wrong? I'm running OSX Yosemite and am using xcode to edit the script, then terminal to run it. I've checked for faulty invisibles, but have found none. commafile.txt is in the same directory as the bash script parsecommas.

EDIT: After running a c++ program and only being able to read the last line of a file, I've realized that this problem may not be with my code but the method which I've used to create text files. I used

```
touch commafile.txt
```

to create my file, and I was only able to read the last line of the file when using getline(file, line) in a c++ program. Has anyone else run into this problem before? What could be wrong with my Mac/Text Editor?

```
cat commafile.txt
```

Only prints the last line in the file, while when I open the file in either XCode or TextEditor all of the lines are displayed. I copy-pasted the contents of a word doc in a box shaped field to commafile.txt.

Comment: I was also wondering if there any characters that IFS doesn't work with? Like colons, semicolons, carats, stars, hash-signs or the like? One more thing to mention is the fact that I created the file parsecommas with touch in terminal.

Comment: No, there are not any characters immune to IFS.

Comment: More important than how you *created* the file is how you *populated* the file. If it's missing a trailing newline, for instance, that'll cause your bug (at least for purposes of the last line in the file being unreadable).

Comment: I'd suggest including the output of both `bash -x parsecommas` and `cat -v commafile.txt` in your question.

Comment: BTW, have you tried reproducing the problem somewhere else, like http://ideone.com/? If you have a reproducer that works there, then there's a good chance that someone else here will be able to repro your problem.

Comment: ...to be clear, **I** can't reproduce this issue: on MacOS, using your exact files copied-and-pasted from the output, I get two lines of output, one containing `bob`, the other containing `joe`.

Comment: I can't post the exact input files at this time...unfortunately, but I will see if I can duplicate the issue by manually typing the file out instead of copy/paste from a word doc. I did resolve the issue by creating the text file in windows, and then downloading the text file from Google Drive to Mac. This might be a niche issue to do with copying from a specific kind of text field in word to Mac text-edit...

Comment: After `touch commafile.txt` you created an empty file, how did you write files into it? Did you flush your c++ stream?

Comment: I populated the file by copy - pasting text from a word doc. I'm not as familiar with C++ as I am with java, but if you're asking if I closed the file to flush the buffer, I didn't know that could be done manually in C++ so I didn't do that.

Comment: Word is not an ASCII editor.  You can't assume that a character that looks like a comma is a comma if you got it from Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `cat filename` only prints the last line, this means your file almost certainly uses CRs (carriage returns, `\r`) rather than LFs (`\n`) or CRLF (`\r\n`) newlines. You can reproduce this bug by creating a file as follows: `printf '%s\r' "bob,mechanic,single,swimming,/bob/tmp,batman," "joe,architect,married,tennis,/joe/tmp,superman,34" >commafile.txt`

This results in `cat` only showing the last line of the file because a `\r` character causes the cursor to go back to the beginning *of the same line* when transitioning between records. This explains your bug, because the `read` shell builtin expects a valid UNIX line, which is terminated by `\n`; if your code contains no `\n`s, then `read` will return a false value and the loop will not run.

You can fix this as follows:

```
# replace \r characters with \n
tr '\r' '\n' <commafile.txt >commafile.fixed && mv commafile{.fixed,.txt}
```

Alternately, you can modify your loop to expect this format instead of a standard UNIX textfile by passing `-d $'\r'` to `read`:

```
while IFS=, read -r -d $'\r' a rest; do
  printf '%s\n' "$a" # less buggy than echo
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think I will go back and try to recreate the issue and fix it as well.